# python function to compute the euclidean distance for every point in an image to center of the image

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to write a function in python that returns for image with width w and height h an array with shape (h,w), where the number at index (i,j) gives the euclidean distance from the point (i,j) to the center of the image. The code is:

---

```
def radial_distance(image):
    h, w = image.shape[:2]
    x, y = center(image)
    for i in range(h):
        for j in range(w):
            image[i,j,:] = np.sqrt((x-i)**2 + (y-j)**2)
    return image
```

---

In the above function, another function 'center' is called which returns the coordinate pair of the image center. To make it more clear, I am posting the function 'center'  here:

---

```
def center(a):
x, y = a.shape[:2]
return ((x-1)/2,(y-1)/2)
```

---

The error given by my function "radial_distance" is:

---

```
radial_distance returned array of wrong shape for input array of shape (3, 3, 3)!
```

---

which means, radial_distance should return a 2D array of shape let's say (3,3) if the input image has shape (3,3,3). One can help me guiding to the right direction and save my time.

Comment: what is the shape of "image" ? and if it is 2D, is its elements integers or array ?

Comment: the image is 3D and its elements are floats

Comment: SORRY! The function should take a 3D array and return a 2D array.